# The code of Show sum of user into label not working

Tags: c#, count, label

I have two dropdownlists one of the country (worlddrdolist) and the another is of states (staatddl) and the button (NumOfUsrBtn) where if the user since click on it then the label will show the total sum of users depending on a country selected from (worlddrdolist) First whatever if the user select the state or not also if the user select the state then it will show the users depending of the country , the below code need update and fix some of part as i tried my best to fix but i coundnt, and i am receiving error message:

> "Must declare the scalar variable "@cou"." also "Must declare the
>   scalar variable "@sta"."

```
 protected void NumOfUsrBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sc))
        {
            string UsrNumSQL = "SELECT COUNT (UsrID)FROM UserInfo WHERE 1=1 AND Country = @cou AND State=@sta";

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(UsrNumSQL, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cou", worlddrdolist.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sta", staatddl.SelectedValue);


                string condition = "";

                if (worlddrdolist.SelectedValue != "")
                {
                    condition += " and Country='" + worlddrdolist.SelectedValue + "'";
                }
                if (staatddl.SelectedValue != "")
                {
                    condition += " and State='" + staatddl.SelectedValue + "'";
                }
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                NumbOfUsersLbl.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how [parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) works.

You need add your parameter value as a parameter in your command, not an additional condition.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@cou", worlddrdolist.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue("@sta", staatddl.SelectedValue);
```

But I *strongly* suspect you just wanna add additional conditions with `AND...` at first place, you don't need to use parameter in your command *at all*. Looks like your conditions is not known at compile time, instead you wanna build them in runtime.

In such a case, just delete unnecessary parts in your query since you wanna add them based on your condition like;

```
string UsrNumSQL = "SELECT COUNT (UsrID)FROM UserInfo WHERE 1=1";
...
...
if (worlddrdolist.SelectedValue != "")
{
    condition += " and Country='" + worlddrdolist.SelectedValue + "'";
}
if (staatddl.SelectedValue != "")
{
    condition += " and State='" + staatddl.SelectedValue + "'";
}
cmd.Connection.Open();
NumbOfUsersLbl.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: Hi @Soner many thanks for your kind reply in fact i decide to make a screen record as my english language is not so perfect as well may i not will explain what happen with code after update i will be more thankful if you have a look on the below link and give your advice      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZT0j5xg6aw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @user3716314 In your video, you still wanna add parameter value in your  if statement. This parameterized queries is not related in this case. Just use them as you did _without_ denfine them in your command. Updated my answer code part at the end, take a look.

Comment: Hi @Soner i have update my code in my post above, can you have a look and i hope that i did the same as you mention if is the same then it did not work it give me in the label  0 value of all countries